# How do I cast an object with computed properties into a type?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, I was trying to convert a string into a type called `Vec2`.

I tried to convince typescript that the return result of `parseVec2` is a type of `Vec2` but it doesn't let me. I gives the same error even I cast it with `as Vec2`.

```js
interface Vec2 {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

function parseVec2(text: string): Vec2 {
    const [_, arg1, num1, arg2, num2] = text.match(/^([xy]):([^,]+),([xy]):([^,]+)$/)!;

    // error
    return {
        [arg1]: +num1,
        [arg2]: +num2
    };
}

console.log(parseVec2('x:1,y:2'));
console.log(parseVec2('y:3,x:4'));
```

- Expected Output

```
{ x: 1, y: 2 }
{ y: 2, x: 4 }
```

- Error

```
Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Vec2': x, yts(2739)
```

If I use `// @ts-ignore` to hide that compile error it runs perfectly, but I don't think it is the right way to do it.

How do I convince typescript that the computed properties `arg1` and `arg2` are `x` and `y` or vise versa?

Comment: If you want to typecast it as `Vec2` first you have to erase type as your result cannot be casted as `Vec2` right away. It should look like `as unknown as Vec2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options but without proper type predicates the only thing you're left are type assertions. As typescript clearly cannot confirm that `arg1`, `arg2` will be `x` and `y` in runtime.

You may erase type and cast it as `Vec2` directly:

```ts
    return {
        [arg1]: +num1,
        [arg2]: +num2
    } as unknown as Vec2;
```

You may cast only keys, still the same type garanties as with `as Vec2`:

```ts
    return {
        [arg1 as 'x']: +num1,
        [arg2 as 'y']: +num2
    };
```

Or implement proper runtime check with [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) or [custom type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```ts
// with assertion function
function assertVec2(obj: unknown): asserts obj is Vec2 {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj == null) 
        throw new Error('Vec2 assert fail. Must be an object');
    if (!('x' in obj) || !('y' in obj)) 
        throw new Error('Vec2 assert fail. Missing required "x" and/or "y" fields');
}

function parseVec2(text: string): Vec2 {
    const [_, arg1, num1, arg2, num2] = text.match(/^([xy]):([^,]+),([xy]):([^,]+)$/)!;

    const result = {
        [arg1]: +num1,
        [arg2]: +num2
    }

    assertVec2(result);

    return result;
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w26R4w)

Wrap the function call with `try .. catch` block and you'll have strong type garanties and meaningfull error messages if something went wrong.

Comment: I didn't know assertion functions exist, maybe that's the better way to write typescript, thanks a lot. Btw I can't cast keys though, `arg1` could be `x` or `y`, so do `arg2`. But `arg1` and `arg2` should never be the same.

Comment: The order doesn't matter as they both have the same type you can't distinguish them one from another. That's why i wrote it has the same type garanties as  `as Vec2`.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidetrack from ts typing details, I would advise using a more robust regex expression. The current one you have will match invalid results such as `x:1,x:1` and `y:1,y:1` as well as invalid numeric values such as `x:foo,y:bar`. Which is probably not your desired output. I would instead use something like this:

```
/^(?<_1>[xy]):([+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?),(?!\k<_1>)([xy]):([+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$/
```

Which will address both of the problems stated above to produce consistent output.

Comment: I wanted to focus on the type issue so I didn't go too deep for the regex part, but thanks for the advise ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove required values in Vec2.

```js
interface Vec2 {
    x?: number,
    y?: number
}
```

Comment: I don't want to break the consistancy of type `Vec2`, that's the reason I want it to be a type :(